# php redirect for Sony Vita?

Tags: php, redirect, user-agent

I am working on a site (that was not created by me) that has a Flash component in it.  It seems the original creator has a php redirect script that should redirect iPad and iPhone to a version of the site without the Flash component in it.  I'm actually not sure if that is even working as I don't have anything to test it on.

My real question is that I also need it to detect the Sony Vita browser and redirect to the version of the site without the Flash component.  But this is a bit out of my depth, I was never very good with php and I've never done something like this.

This is the current redirect code:

```
<?php
$ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

//スマフォ
if((strpos($ua,'iPhone')!==false)||(strpos($ua,'iPod')!==false)||(strpos($ua,'Android')!==false)) {
header("location: top_i.php");

//IPAD
}elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')){
header("location: top_i.php");

//PC
}else{
header("location: top.php");
}
?>
```

Could anyone help explain what I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
|| (strpos($ua,'Playstation Vita')!==false)
```

next to (strpos($ua,'Android')!==false)

should give you something like

```
if((strpos($ua,'iPhone')!==false)||(strpos($ua,'iPod')!==false)||(strpos($ua,'Android')!==false) || (strpos($ua,'Playstation Vita')!==false))
```

or add a new if statement

```
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Playstation Vita')){
   header("location: top_i.php");
}
```

Before the final "else"

Answer (score 0):

The Playstation Vita Browser uses a custom user agent string so it *SHOULD* be code like this:

```
<?php
$ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

//スマフォ
if ((strpos($ua,'iPhone')!==false) || (strpos($ua,'iPod')!==false) || (strpos($ua,'Android')!==false)) {
  header("location: top_i.php");
//IPAD
} elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')){
  header("location: top_i.php");
} elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Playstation Vita')){
  header("location: top_i.php"); // or some other page you like to redirect to

} else {
  //PC
  header("location: top.php");
}
?>
```